# How do I create a random variance matrix (x'x)/N with confidence that it will be invertible?

Tags: r, variance, covariance, covariance-matrix

I see some similar threads, but no answer that I know how to apply to this question. I wish to create a variance matrix for a (pseudo)random matrix $X$ with dimensions $K \times N$, where each row $k$ represents $N$ draws of a random variable with mean $\mu_k$, $\sigma^2_k=10$, and 10 was arbitrarily selected. The goal is to create $X$ such that $(X'X)/N$ is computationally invertible. I'm using R... so that defines the bounds of "computationally invertible".

So far, I've done the following, which I assumed would be sufficient. The last line points out to me that I am probably confused about how easy it is to acquire linear dependence.

```
N<-50
K<-round(runif(1,1,10))
ex<-rnorm(1,0,10)
x<-matrix(rnorm(N,ex,10)) #one row is already created.
tick<-0 #cheap trick to make sure your loop repeated successfully.
for(i in 2:K){
ex<-rnorm(1,0,10) #the means should each be different, should help?
holding<-as.matrix(rnorm(N,ex,1)) #it's an Nx1, k=1
x<-cbind(x,holding)
tick<-tick+1
}
print(tick)
x<-t(x) #x is now K by N
det(cov(x)) #It's computationally 0 with great consistency.
```

Primary question: How do I make one such random matrix $X$ such that it does have an invertible variance matrix?

Aside: Could someone explain why this is so frequently singular, since I thought by LLN each column/row should converge to their uncorrelated state of linear independence? Is the "computationally" singular restriction so powerful?
I've noticed that it's actually working sometimes if I set $N$ as arbitrarily small, such as 5.

Comment: Have you tried using cov instead of var?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was just doing (t(x)%*%x)/N for most of it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. If $x$ is $(NxK)$ instead of $(KxN)$, then the problem disappears. The columns are not independent, since each column is: $N_i=x_{i,1},x_{i,2}...x_{i,K}$, and after 50+ draws or so, one linear combination of them is likely to be similar to another to a great degree. This explains why it worked when N is small.

Comment: I was going to suggest that too. There are techniques to estimate an invertible covariance matrix when the number of variables is larger than the sample, but I try to avoid using them unless absolutely necessary.